# Making MSVC compiler GCC complient?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc, compiler-construction

Is there a way to make the msvc compiler as strict as gcc? MSVC lets me do some pretty crazy things that result in hundreds of errors when I compile in linux.

Thanks

Comment: @Milo - I will be watching this question very closely.  I am currently porting a giant codebase from MSVC to the GNU toolchain, and I'm feeling your pain.

Comment: Could you provide some examples? My impression was always that MSVC disallowed lots of things that were perfectly valid C (C99 at least) because they're not in C++, and it's essentially a C++ compiler pretending C is a subset of C++...

Comment: @R: Since he's going from MSVC to Linux I'd not be bothered too much by C99/C++03 specific code that is there and not supported by GCC (provided the recent enough version of GCC is being used).

Comment: I'd be interested in examples too. Having worked on a number of codebases that targeted VC++ and gcc simultaneously, the programmers working with gcc used to introduce VC++ warnings far more often than the other way about. (Most were type narrowings, conversions from int to float, conversions from double to float.) VC++'s /W4 seemed much more anal about common issues than gcc's -Wall. (You can interpret this as VC++ being unnecessarily picky, or gcc being slack, as you see fit.)The code was of course pretty sound once we got it warning-free on both.

Comment: @Milo: Different compilers enforce different things. Compile with both of them and get over it.

Comment: Indeed, my impression is that MSVC warns about any C that's not also valid C++, and probably even things that are valid but not "best-practices" in C++.

Comment: @R. +1 to comment -- note that IMHO, C code that won't compile as C++ isn't very good C code ;)

Comment: @Billy, really?  Every time I see `int *a = (int *)malloc(12)` I die a little.

Comment: @Milo Why would you want MSVC compiler to be "compliAnt" with GCCs bugs and proprietary extensions instead of wanting to make your environment standards-compliant? BTW, GCC doesn't warn about most of the implicit narrowing/signed-unsigned conversions even with /Wall. `size_t a = -1;`, `uint a = 1; double b = -a;`, etc. Moreover even some standard functions like `wcslen` don't work on some architectures like FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get started we'd need the version you are on (for MSVC), what sort of errors you hit (compile time, link time or run time) and so on.

Assuming you are on a relatively current version (MSVC 2008 SP1) and being bugged by compiler errors, I'd suggest the following:

- Your program's entry point is called `main` and not `_tmain` or `WinMain`
- /W4: Treat warnings as errors
- Remove any function that begins with `_` -- they are implementation specific
- No Win32 APIs either
- No platform specific threading
- Check if you have same signedness for `char`
- How do the two implementations treat `wchar_t`
- No Safe Exception Handling or inline assembly magic
- No COM/MFC either

Comment: My problem is not errors in msvc, the problem is msvc lets too many things slide by while gcc is more strict

Comment: @Milo: The above list is indicative of what may cause grief. Without any example of from your side your question becomes difficult to answer.

Answer (score 5):

A better question would be: Are MSVC, g++, or any other compiler *standard* compliant, and if so, to the same standard version? You shouldn't rely upon a common set of non-standard behavior. Personally, I'm responsible for over 500KLOC of C++ that compile on both g++ 4.1.x and VC7.1. There can be alot of give and take from both compilers.

Both compilers have either language or library extensions. g++ tends to be better about putting library extensions in a separate namespace. VC, at least older version, not so good. Both have language extensions that are on by default, or can be enabled (or disabled) with compiler switches. You're best disabling all language extensions.

The higher the warning level on each compiler you can set, the better - and don't disregard warnings from either compiler without just reason.

For windows, by default I use the following options: `/W3 /wd4355 /wd4805 /wd4710`. I'd like to use `/W4`, but 3rd party libs make this level unbearable.
For g++, I use `-Wall -Wextra`. I'd also like to use `-Wold-style-cast`, but I rely on too many 3rd party libraries that violate this one.

Each compiler warns about different constructs, or warns about them differently. You're best off to pay attention to output from both compilers and find the subset of code between them that produces zero warnings, at as high of a warning level as you can possibly set.

Comment: +1.  There are several options you can set that will help, but at the end of the day there is no substitute for building the project with both compilers on a regular basis.  I've been building the same code with g++ and Visual Studio every day for 5+ years and aside from a couple of things like std::tr1 quirks and the use of `typename` there are very few things that work on one but not the other.  Write portably and you shouldn't have problems.

Answer (score 2):

The [/Za (Disable Language Extensions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) option disables a number of Microsoft-specific [keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9.aspx) and [extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx).